# Map the data according to image in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop the API data into a table as in the image, but I am getting an error.

I want date-wise data main module name must come as table headers, and corresponding sub-modules will come under the main module as in the image.

**Note**: the main module will have more than one sub-module as in the image.

The last table header will be custom. It will have all the custom module names displayed date-wise.

```
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {predefined.map((personData, index) => {          ///mapping mainmodules
        return (
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={styles.th}>{personData.mainModule}</th>
            </tr>
            {personData.submodule
              .filter((e) => e.completed == true)            ///maping submodules
              .map((subModule) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <tr>
                      <td style={styles.td}>{subModule.subModuleName}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </>
                );
              })}
          </thead>
        );
      })}

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style={styles.th}>custum</th>
        </tr>

        {custom.map((personData, index) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td style={styles.td}>{personData.name}</td>{" "}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </thead>
```

I have created a code sandbox of complete code I tried.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-http-fdl0f?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: check the console log: the returned data have "Predefined" with the capital "P". Correct it in the `useEffect`, and try again.

Comment: @MarioVernari hello sir can u pls help me to make the data displayed as in the image  it will be very kind of u

Comment: @MarioVernari i have changed as u asked

Comment: What does `e.completed` do. Is it another filter to be added?

Comment: @NeelDsouza e.complted  is a fiild its says if the submodule is true if it true then display it if it is false dont disaplay it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `filter` like this. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

```
{predefined.filter(item => item.module === 'mainmodule1').map((module, index) => {
    return (
        <td key={index}></td>
    )
})}

{predefined.filter(item => item.module === 'mainmodule2').map((module, index) => {
    return (
        <td key={index}></td>
    )
})}
```

Comment: i cant do this  mainmodule1 mainmodule2 can be anything its dynamic

Comment: item.module === 'mainmodule2'   here mainmodule2 is a dynamic data that is fechected from api

Comment: Yes. How is your data grouped? Did you create the api yourself? You can arrange your data according to type or group name like mainmodule1, mainmodule2 etc and use that to filter the data in react.

Comment: the answer u have given is checking if main module1 is there that is wrong i cant do that as i have said the mainModule  is dynamic and anything can be fectched in that filed . its not possible to add if conditions to all the dymaic data that is coming in mainmodule

Comment: item.module === 'mango'  i cant do this i hope u understand my problem @Ameriz

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Can you elaborate more on your problem with an example to understand better.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token 52ae6ea1759163fcdab109ca0f883afb7b2df857`
      }
    };

    axios
      .get(
        "/all-activity-data/?customer=20",
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        let filteredData = {};
        let filteredData2 = {date: ''};

        res.data.Predefined.forEach((e) => {
          if (e.completed === true){
            filteredData[e.date] = filteredData[e.date] ? [...filteredData[e.date], e] : [e]
            filteredData2[e.mainModule] = ""
          };
        });
        setheaders(filteredData2);
        console.log(filteredData)
        setcustom(filteredData);
        setpredefined(res.data.Predefined);
      });
  }, []);

...

return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
      {Object.keys(headers).map((personData, index) => {
        return (
              <th style={styles.th}>{personData}</th>
              );
            })}
            </tr>
          </thead>
{/* <tbody> */}
      {Object.keys(custom).map((personData, index) => {
        return (
            <tr>
              <td>{personData}</td>
              {custom[personData].map(el => <td>{el.submodule}</td>)}
            </tr>
            
        );
      })}
{/* </tbody> */}

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style={styles.th}>custum</th>
        </tr>

        {/* {custom.map((personData, index) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td style={styles.td}>{personData.name}</td>{" "}
            </tr>
          );
        })} */}
      </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code that you’re looking for I guess.

demo codesandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-night-lrjuf?file=/src/App.js

output looks like this

[image]

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import "./styles.css";

export default function ActivityTracker(props) {
  const [predefined, setpredefined] = useState([]);
  const [custom, setcustom] = useState([]);
  var pikerdate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      ...// your config
    };

    axios
      .get(
        "customer/get-all-activity-data/?customer=20",
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        let filteredData = [];
        let filteredData2 = [];

        res.data.Custom.forEach((e) => {
          if (e.completed === true) filteredData.push(e);
        });
        filteredData.sort(
          (a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime()
        );
        setcustom(filteredData);
        setpredefined(res.data.Predefined);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(custom);
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style={styles.th}>Date</th>
        </tr>

        {predefined.map((personData, index) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td style={styles.td}>{personData.date}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </thead>
      {predefined.map((personData, index) => {
        return (
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={styles.th}>{personData.mainModule}</th>
            </tr>
            {predefined
              .filter(
                (e) => e.completed && e.mainModule === personData.mainModule
              )
              .map((subModule, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <td style={styles.td}>{subModule.mainModule}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
          </thead>
        );
      })}

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style={styles.th}>custum</th>
        </tr>

        {custom.map((personData, index) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td style={styles.td}>{personData.activity}</td>{" "}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </thead>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ur close to the answer . ur showing the main modules repetdly insted of submodule

Comment: @jisaks I am sure you can modify that right?

Comment: no i am not able to do that pls help

Comment: I have edited the sandbox now it is showing submodules check https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-night-lrjuf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the answer is still not corret when a submodule is added a entire new row is created based on the main module in ur code

Comment: i have updated the codesandbox  the mainmodule fild is correct in the codesandbox pls help me itrate the submodules based on the date

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lehmann-vhqpr

Comment: u have hardcoded   the main modules to display submodules which is not suit for my reqirement it